# How do I know if L3 Cache is set- or fully-associative in linux?

Tags: linux, caching

I am trying to know if L3 Cache is set- or fully associative in Linux, and I use the following commands to get the details of the cache. However, the results are a little confusing for me to understand.

```
getconf -a | grep CACHE
```

```
LEVEL1_ICACHE_SIZE        32768
LEVEL1_ICACHE_ASSOC       8
LEVEL1_ICACHE_LINESIZE    64
LEVEL1_DCACHE_SIZE        32768
LEVEL1_DCACHE_ASSOC       8
LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE    64
LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE         1048576
LEVEL2_CACHE_ASSOC        16
LEVEL2_CACHE_LINESIZE     64
LEVEL3_CACHE_SIZE         11534336
LEVEL3_CACHE_ASSOC        11
LEVEL3_CACHE_LINESIZE     64
LEVEL4_CACHE_SIZE         0
LEVEL4_CACHE_ASSOC        0
LEVEL4_CACHE_LINESIZE     0
```

It seems that the L3 Cache is 11-way set-associative cache. However, when I used another command it said the L3 Cache is fully associative.

```
sudo dmidecode -t cache
```

```
Handle 0x0048, DMI type 7, 27 bytes
Cache Information
Socket Designation: L3 Cache
Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
Location: Internal
Installed Size: 11264 kB
Maximum Size: 11264 kB
Supported SRAM Types: Synchronous
Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
Speed: Unknown
Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
System Type: Unified
Associativity: Fully Associative
```

It makes me confused.

I want to ask, which one is the true result? What is the meaning of `LEVEL3_CACHE_ASSOC`? Why the number of `LEVEL3_CACHE_ASSOC` is not power of two?

Comment: There is no requirement for the associativity to be a power of two. Number of sets is usually a power of two, so that some of the address bits can be used as the index.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Skylake-X has the 1.375 MB of L3 slice per core. Yours must be the 8 core system with an 11 MB L3, which is 11-way set-associative: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/123547/intel-xeon-silver-4110-processor-11m-cache-2-10-ghz/specifications.html

As I commented, there is no power-of-two requirement for the associativity.

As to why `dmidecode` is saying something else, it is either an error in the DMI table, or a bug in the decoder. The [spec](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.7.0.pdf) has the following table, where 11-way is not one of the options, so it should say "Other" instead.

> Table 40 – Cache Information: Associativity field

| Byte Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 01h | Other |
| 02h | Unknown |
| 03h | Direct Mapped |
| 04h | 2-way Set-Associative |
| 05h | 4-way Set-Associative |
| 06h | Fully Associative |
| 07h | 8-way Set-Associative |
| 08h | 16-way Set-Associative |
| 09h | 12-way Set-Associative |
| 0Ah | 24-way Set-Associative |
| 0Bh | 32-way Set-Associative |
| 0Ch | 48-way Set-Associative |
| 0Dh | 64-way Set-Associative |
| 0Eh | 20-way Set-Associative |